# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION Android Java Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception

My eclipse (which I still use for Android development) has recently started crashing. I will just be scrolling around the code base, and suddenly, poof, eclipse gone. I tried 3 different jre versions but no luck. Any suggestions from anyone?

Full text of hs_err_pidxxxx.log is at
[pastebin.com/7GV9hGar](http://pastebin.com/7GV9hGar)

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ff00ddf, pid=3312, tid=0x000000000000222c
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b14) (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x4c0ddf]
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
Current thread (0x000000001d199000):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8748, stack(0x000000001e590000,0x000000001e690000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000008

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x000000001d29d240, RDX=0x0000000000001000
RSP=0x000000001e68bcf0, RBP=0x000000002005bd48, RSI=0x000000001d29d240, RDI=0x000000001e68c230
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000024495d10, R10=0x000000001e68c230, R11=0x000000002342ae50
R12=0x000000002005ab78, R13=0x000000001d1f27d8, R14=0x000000001e68bdd8, R15=0x000000001e68bdf8
RIP=0x000000006ff00ddf, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010287

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001e68bcf0)
0x000000001e68bcf0:   000000002005c078 000000002005bd48
0x000000001e68bd00:   000000001d29d240 000000001e68c230
0x000000001e68bd10:   000000002005bd48 000000001e68be48
0x000000001e68bd20:   0000000000000008 000000006ff025f9
0x000000001e68bd30:   000000002005c078 000000000000025e
0x000000001e68bd40:   0000000000000001 000000001d2a23b0
0x000000001e68bd50:   000000001e68cc08 000000006ff4c1b0
0x000000001e68bd60:   00000000212b0450 000000001bfd2a40
0x000000001e68bd70:   000000001ee4cf70 000000001e68bea0
0x000000001e68bd80:   000000001bfd2a40 000000000000000d
0x000000001e68bd90:   000000001e68c230 000000006ff04383
0x000000001e68bda0:   000000001e68c230 0000000000000001
0x000000001e68bdb0:   0000000000000001 000000001e68be48
0x000000001e68bdc0:   00000000212b04a0 00000000212b8438
0x000000001e68bdd0:   0000000000078220 000000001bfd2a40
0x000000001e68bde0:   0000000000000400 00000000256f5470
```

Comment: Switch to Android Studio! I've not had any problems with it and it's way more natural to develop for Android. Pretty easy learning curve.

Comment: @mWhitley thats in the pipeline. Unfortunately not in my control to push that any faster so kinda stuck with eclipse for now.

Comment: @petey I saw other threads with similar error but not this one. I will give this a try now